# php: refreshing script without browser

Tags: php

I know that this can be done with a cron tab, but I was wondering if there was any way to refresh a php script at a certain interval, say one second, without using a browser/javaScript.

I have a device that outputs data constantly and I need a php script that can run independent for a browser to load that data into a database should it change.

My server is a Linux box and it houses a lot of different development projects so I just have access to one partition of it.

The device is actually using a node and python to pull the data and I cam creating a web interface and a logging system for a charting interface I am creating.  So it needs to pullt he data at a consistent interval for charting the data I am storing.

Thank you all for your fatnastic responses and giving me a lot to work from here. I will look into the solutions offered and see if I can be more specific in my request.

Comment: so, what's wrong with using cron?

Comment: @PeterKrejci Sometimes crontab is not available, for instance, on some shared hosting.

Comment: Also, it only can be run in 1 minute intervals at the shortest.  The other side of it is the server setup makes it difficult to add cron tab's that I can access.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum timeframe in cron is 1 minute. You need to run the PHP script as some sort of daemon (background process) on the server if you want to process data constantly.

A simple, but not very CPU efficient way is to run something like:

```
$stop = false;
while ( ! $stop ) {
   sleep(1); // Sleep for one second
   if ( shouldProcess() ) { // Check if there is anything to process
      doProcess(); // Run whatever task necessary
   }
}
```

There is also a PEAR package http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon for handling things like init.d behavior and logging.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much!  So the doProcess could be something like 
    doProcess('foo.php');

Also, would I have to save this file in etc folder or browse to it once to trigger it? Thanks!

Comment: But this will operate with a period of 1 second + the time taken to run doprocess() - not run doprocess() every second.

Comment: That is probably ok... one second is ideal, but since this is a web application it can only go as fast as it can go....

Where should I store this type of file and how do I trigger it?  Thanks!

Comment: doProcess(); should be a PHP function performing the tasks you want to  get done. You would leave it running as a user on the server (not root) with php myscript.php & or use something like screen. The System_Daemon package is best if it's a serious application.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will work with this and see if I can get it to function.

Comment: @symcbean Yes, but it sounds like what he is trying to do cannot be run in parallel. He could also set a very low sleep time using usleep to run it more often.

Answer (score 0):

You're right - with a cron job. Assuming you're running Linux or something pop `#!/usr/bin/php` on the first line of your PHP file, then run `crontab -e` and pop in `* * * * *     /path/to/myphpscript.php` to run it every minute.

Every second is setting yourself up for failure. If you really must, keep a track of how long the script has been running and set it to loop with a `sleep(1)` at the end of the loop until the script has been running for 59 seconds. Much cleaner solution.

Comment: If crontab isn't available, you're out of luck. You could use a separate machine to trigger it. `* * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.site.com/script.php 2>&1> /dev/null` in the crontab of any machine will request that script once per minute. Far preferable to have it on the local machine, though.

Answer (score 0):

Without crontab there are a couple solutions. Nothing as efficient as contab but still, they work.
There are paid services [online](http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/) that will invoke one of your script/pages at a given interval. Working pretty much like crontab except for some permissions differences.

Also, you could setup your pages to check, every time someone visits your site, if its "time" to reload the data. For example you could have a table in your database where you write everytime you "load data" what time it was. Then just check the current time and wait till its an hour old to reload. Its quite similar to caching.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of questions there.

You want to repeat stuff at a 1 second interval - but if you're driving this froma browser how do you deal with concurrent access? HTTP doesn't support pushing data from server to client but you can simulate it with comet. 1 second is a very short time for a HTTP transaction - and typically most of the delay will be down to network latency - how important is jitter?

> I have a device that outputs data constantly and I need a php script that can run independent fo a browser

You're right - the script collecting this data must never be accessible from a browser. One obvious solution is to run it as a daemon (i.e. a script which does not exit under normal operations but uses usleep and a loop to carry out jobs at fixed intervals). However you've not mentioned what OS this is running on (which has a lot to do with how you go about writing a daemon). Nor have you given any indication of how the device data is accessed.

The using a daemon is not obvious suggests you've got a lot of reading to do - it'd be a lot simpler to use something like nagios or statsd to handle the scheduling / logging.

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding your question, I just give the solution for refreshing the pages without javascript/cron jobs. We can refresh the page by using meta tags

For example, Refresh document every 30 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
```

Hope this helps.